# Apply HTTP headers for specific domain

Tags: nginx, proxy, http-headers

I have the web application served by nginx.
I need to add

- subdomain (e.g. `cool.myapp.com`)
- all requests to `cool.myapp.com`, `cool.myapp.com/<anything>` should lead to `www.example.com` and prepend with custom headers.

I need it, because I use `iframe` on one of my pages 
`<iframe src='http://www.example.com'></iframe>` It would work fine, but I need requests to www.example.com to contain specific headers.

Thus I plan to create this subdomain and use `<iframe src='cool.example.com/<anything>'></iframe>`

Can't do it via JavaScript and Ajax because of some reasons (one of them is CORS issue) so I want my `nginx` do the job.

Can it be achieved? What should I look at for at nginx configs?

**Update**

I looked and solution like this could help, probably

`location cool.myapp.com {
    proxy_pass http://www.example.com
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
}`

Comment: rephrase your question so it easier for one to understand and use multiple paras instead of big chunk

Comment: Tried to be more clear on purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to. So it'd be in my case

```
server {
  server_name domain.tld;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://upstream;
    proxy_set_header Header-Name "headerValue";
  }
}
```